# Return 1 instead of infinite in division by 0

Tags: actionscript-3, math

As the math principles says, when some number is divided by 0 it will be `infinite`, but, in my case, when it becomes infinite I need it to be `1`, how can I achieve this?

```
if(obj.x > -180){
    left_fade.alpha = -(1/obj.x);
} else{
    left_fade.alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't change mathematics, integer division, or floating point division, but you can write code to account for this special case without having to resort to that.

Comment: With `-(1/obj.x)` if your **obj.x** is 0, when tracing do you get **`infinity`** or do you get **`-infinity`**. Check which one your code gives and do an **IF** statement inside that `if(obj.x > -180)` block.

Comment: PS: Please respond on Answers instead of just down-voting them. I've edited mine to be clearer. Let me know if there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple, I hope I'm not missing the point completely...

```
if(obj.x > -180){
    left_fade.alpha = (obj.x==0) ? 1 : -(1/obj.x);
} else{
    left_fade.alpha = 0;
}
```

That can be problematic if obj.x is a floating point number and not an integer. In that case you have to define a threshold to decide if it's zero or not:

```
if(obj.x > -180){
    left_fade.alpha = (Math.abs(obj.x)<1e-10) ? 1 : -(1/obj.x);
} else{
    left_fade.alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: absolute value, I realized that it was not C afterwards and I don't know actionscript-3 so I'm guessing here. `Math.abs()` should work, else can be done with another ternary expression.

Answer (score 0):

As your denominator approaches 1 (from a larger value), the quotient becomes smaller and smaller.  But it becomes larger and larger (*approaching* infinity) as the denominator approaches zero from 1.  This is why you will need a constraint against anything below the integer 1.  Try this:

```
if(obj.x > -180 && Math.abs(obj.x) >= 1)
{
    left_fade.alpha = -(1/obj.x);
} else {
    left_fade.alpha = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions are all good ... but you can keep your code shorter and concise by taking advantage of *falsy* values

0 is considered false in a boolean statement, so in an OR statement the following value would be returned `0 || 1 -> 1`

so your division can simply become

```
left_fade.alpha = -(1/ (obj.x || 1));
```

which means: divide 1 by obj.x, or 1 if obj.x is 0